# Converting array to string looping issue

Tags: c#, .net

I have a foreach loop going that is adding e-mail address to an array.  At the end I join the array and push it into a string.

I have an issue when someone in the database has a blank email address it messes up my logic.  Can someone help me fix this?

```
TestGuy1: 
TestGuy2: 2@2.com
TestGuy3: 3@3.com
```

With the above information it creates a 3 length array and then turns it into a string like so:

```
sEmailList  "2@2.com,3@3.com,"  string
```

Code:

```
DataTable GetUserReportsToChain = objEmployee.GetUserReportsToChain(LoginID, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Connection").ToString());

int RowCount = GetUserReportsToChain.Rows.Count;
string[] aEmailList = new string[RowCount];
int iCounter = 0;
foreach (DataRow rRow in GetUserReportsToChain.Rows)
{
    if (rRow["usrEmailAddress"].ToString() != "")
    {
        aEmailList[iCounter] = rRow["usrEmailAddress"].ToString();
        iCounter++;
        //String email = rRow["usrEmailAddress"].ToString(); 
    }
}

string sEmailList = String.Join(",", aEmailList);
```

Any idea how I can fix this when the database has a blank value for e-mail?

Comment: Please provide "expected" value. Also I see nothing particularly wrong about your string - just make code that uses it resilient to empty elements.

Comment: When `rRow["usrEmailAddress"].ToString()==""` is true then there are empty slots in `aEmailList` not set to an email address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All in one

```
var sEmailList = String.Join(",", 
      GetUserReportsToChain.Rows
      .Cast<DataRow>()
      .Select(m => m["usrEmailAddress"].ToString())
      .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)));
```

Comment: `Cast<DataRow>` ==> `Cast<DataRow>()`

Comment: @JamesWilson : all but first:  `DataTable GetUserReportsToChain = objEmployee.GetUserReportsToChain(LoginID, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Connection").ToString());
`

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `List<string>` instead of fixed size array. Or simple LINQ query that returns non-empty strings.

```
List<string> aEmailList = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow rRow in GetUserReportsToChain.Rows)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rRow["usrEmailAddress"].ToString()))
    {
        aEmailList.Add(rRow["usrEmailAddress"].ToString());
    }
}
string sEmailList = String.Join(",", aEmailList);
```

Comment: Ok I am going to try and implement this solution.

Comment: It gives me this error on your very first line above. Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: Needs the new keyword:

List<string> aEmailList = new List<string>();

Answer (score 2):

you can try with

```
String.Join(",", aEmailList.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your if statement to:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rRow["usrEmailAddress"].ToString().Trim())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 3.0 or higher:

```
String.Join(",", aEmailList.Where(s => s.Trim() != ""));
```

Comment: This needs 4.0 to compile, not 3.0

Comment: Right you are. For 3.0, you would have to convert the result of "Where" with "ToArray".